# Porque no puedo cargar una imagen desde una url Xamarin Android?

Tags: xamarin.android

Mi problema es el siguiente: Desde una url quiero cargar una imagen en xamarin; en UWP la muestra correctamente pero en android no la muestra(Ya puse en android mannifest los permisos de internet y tambien useCleartextTraffic=true ya que la url es desde http a parte fui a configuraciones avanzadas de las opciones de android y cambie Implementacion de HttpClient: "Administrado" e Implementacion de SSL/TLS: "TLS 1.2 + nativo" pero nada ): alguna ayuda?

```
           Product product = (Product)itemProduct;
           string imageurl=  App.AppProfile.IpServiceCentralExt+ "/Common/Images/Products/"+product.Codigo+".png";
            ImageProduct = ImageSource.FromUri(
                        new Uri(imageurl)
            );

            //ImageProduct = imageurl;
            IsVisibleModalDialog = true;

      <Image Grid.Row="1" Source="{Binding ImageProduct}"  WidthRequest="150" HeightRequest="150"></Image>
```

[image: Url de la imagen del producto]

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas algo que tome tu URL y lo "convierta" a un recurso o imagen que puedas mostrar en tu ImageView.

Utiliza este void y luego lo llamas pasandole tu URL:

Void:

```
private Bitmap GetImageBitmapFromUrl(string url)
{
    Bitmap imageBitmap = null;

    using (var webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        var imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(url);
        if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.Length > 0)
        {
            imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
        }
    }

    return imageBitmap;
}
```

Luego lo llamas así:

```
ImageView ImgView;

                ImgView= FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView);

                ImgView.SetImageBitmap(GetImageBitmapFromUrl("Aqui va tu URL"));
```